# trying to link two or more pages in html but error loading page

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm building my blog, I have done everything perfectly, but when it came to linking two pages, it gave me this error

error loading page

however, I have made sure that all my files are in the same directory!

```
<ul class="flex-lg flex-lg-row justify-content-lg-center align-content-lg-center">
    <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="travelling.html">Travelling</a></li>
    <li><a href="health.html">Health</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos and videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about me</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

here is my code

what is the problem?

Comment: Well, your code is correct. What is the error message?

Comment: error loading page

Comment: what are you using to build this in? It might be breaking on the lack of closing </ul> tag if it's trying to check the validity of your code

Comment: from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: actaully there is a closing tag but i forgot to mention it in the post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local

Comment: Are you using any server side programming language or a CMS? Try uploading this to your local machine and see if it works.

Comment: " it gave me this error". What is "it"? Typically web apps like blogs use more than 1 technology in their stack, the origin of this error is unclear.  All you've included is HTML, and typically HTML doesn't have "errors" and is in fact known for being quite fault-tolerant

Comment: im not using any server yet, I'm just building it for practicing my programming!

Comment: the error is " error loading page"

Comment: from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5 GET file:///C:/Users/travelling.html net::ERR_FAILED

Answer (score 1):

Hi your code is correct and you are saying that you will getting an error. In my point of view this type of errors occurs when you will made changes in your .htaccess file. if you made changes in your .htaccess file this code will help you

**Replace this :-**

```
<li class="current-menu-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="travelling.html">Travelling</a></li>
<li><a href="health.html">Health</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Photos and videos</a></li>
<li><a href="#">about me</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

**To this :-**

```
<li class="current-menu-item"><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/travelling.html">Travelling</a></li>
<li><a href="/health.html">Health</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Photos and videos</a></li>
<li><a href="#">about me</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

**If these changes not working so use this code**

```
<li class="current-menu-item"><a href="index">/Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/travelling">Travelling</a></li>
<li><a href="/health">Health</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Photos and videos</a></li>
<li><a href="#">about me</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
```

Or you will not made changes in your .htaccess file so you also try this code.

Hope this will help you.

Thank you.

Comment: @aman, I'll try to give you correct answer wait for another answer :-)

Comment: Can you give me the url of this project I have an solution and I want to analyse the code and want to find exact problem or and I'm sorry for late reply

Comment: I'm sorry but this project i haven't uploaded offıcially to the intwrnet,, however if you want i can send it to you by email

Answer (score 1):

your code is correct, you made changes in your .htaccess file.
remove .php, .html, .htm extensions with .htaccess.

**try this code**

```
<li class="current-menu-item"><a href="index">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="travelling">Travelling</a></li>
<li><a href="health">Health</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Photos and videos</a></li>
<li><a href="#">about me</a></li>
<li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: doesnt work too! and it gave me this error in the console: from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https

Answer (score 1):

**Finally this help you**

I only add website main url before files in anchor tag.

```
<li class="current-menu-item"><a href="https://yourwebsite.com/index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="https://yourwebsite.com/travelling.html">Travelling</a></li>
<li><a href="https://yourwebsite.com/health.html">Health</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Photos and videos</a></li>
<li><a href="#">about me</a></li>
<li><a href="https://yourwebsite.com/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```